# Транскрипция слова "культура"

Tags: транскрипция

Культура - [кул'-ту-ра]. Верно ли? Подскажите, пожалуйста. И какие ещё существуют способы записи транскрипции?

Answer (score 1):

В вузе филологи транскрибируют это слово так: [к˚ул'т˚ýръ]. Для школьников достаточно того разбора, что приводите вы.